# Remove the first 6 columns using Linux

Tags: linux, sed

From a text file, I want to remove the first 6 columns. I tried sed as follows, but I have to do it six times (one for each column). Is there any efficient way to do it (or pass the 6 columns at once for sed)?

```
sed -i -r 's/(\s+)?\S+//1' file
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which character separates the columns?

Comment: Wight spaces between them

Comment: This might help you https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222121/how-to-remove-a-column-or-multiple-columns-from-file-using-shell-command/222123

Comment: Thanks Guys! That was helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this within regex and quantifying braces if a column consists of non-whitespace characters with optional leading spaces:

```
sed -i -r 's/^((\s+)?\S+){6} *//' file
```

Comment: I suggest to replace `{6}/` with `{6} /` to remove a leading white space.

Comment: @downvoter, I'd appreciate an explanation for your downvote. I may either improve or remove the answer.